# Where to store global data in Angular?

Tags: angular

I decided to learn Angular 4 and ASP Net Core 2 at once by building blog application. I came to a point where I want to store global data for every component.

For example, I want when the user logs in to pass the logged state to my navbar component and by that I can change the buttons, show the current user name etc.

How from my LoginComponent I can pass data to my NavbarComponent and so on?

Comment: How about storing in service and adding that in module's provider ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Since you are starting out I'd stick with EventEmitters and @inputs and sharing data via the angular docs, but Redux would be the go to for more complex data stores that are shared across every component.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-observable-input?file=app/app.component.ts) with example of how to apply observable and @Input data changes accross components with a service.**

You will need a service and Rxjs with subscriptions to do it the angular way:

```
import {Injectable}             from '@angular/core';
import {Subject}                from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserNameService {

    execChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {}

    /**
     * Use to change user name 
     * @data type: string
     */
    userNameChange(data: string) {
        this.execChange.next(data);
    }
}
```

And then in every component where you want to have the user name changed add a subscription:

```
constructor(private userNameService : UserNameService) {
        this._subscription_user_name = this.userNameService.execChange.subscribe((value) => {
            this.userName= value; // this.username will hold your value and modify it every time it changes 
        });
}
```

How to change the value so that every subscription can moddify the values? Call your `execChange` function in your service:

```
this.userNameService.userNameChange('Thor');
```

EDIT: @Vikas comment is correct and quite self explanatory... youn need to add the service to ngModule providers array or you will get a headache dealing with unknown provider errors.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [UserNameService]
})
```

If you need to persist your data across tabs or when refreshing the page, use `localstorage` as well.

Comment: I think you should also mention that If we want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share state across the application we should register it with the ` @NgModule's` providers array;)

Comment: here you have to inject to all component I think it is drawback.do you know a way to have it with minimal configurations.

Answer (score 3):

It might be overkill for starting to learn Angular, but as @ShellNinja pointed out, you might consider a library offering state management, e.g. [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform).

From the [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md) docs:

> RxJS powered state management for Angular applications, inspired by
>   Redux
>
> @ngrx/store is a controlled state container designed to help write
>   performant, consistent applications on top of Angular. Core tenets:
>
> State is a single, immutable data structure. Actions describe state
>   changes. Pure functions called reducers take the previous state and
>   the next action to compute the new state. State accessed with the
>   Store, an observable of state and an observer of actions. These core
>   principles enable building components that can use the OnPush change
>   detection strategy giving you intelligent, performant change detection
>   throughout your application.

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is good practice to keep username  at localStorage, i think.

so this Appservice subscribing to Webservice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  protected authHeaders = new Headers({'Authorization': localStorage['accessToken']});
  protected headers = new Headers(this.authHeaders);

  constructor(protected http: Http) {
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
    let info = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
    return this.http.post('/login', info, {headers: this.headers})
      .map(res => res.headers.get('Authorization'))
      .catch(this.handle);
  }
}
```

and here is component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  private username: string;
  private password: string;
  private showErrorMessage: boolean = false;

  constructor(private service: AppService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
  }

  login() {
    this.service.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        localStorage.setItem('userName', this.username);
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data);
        this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
      },
      () => { this.showErrorMessage = true }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios for data you want to share:

1. If the data is changing dynamically and ofc you would want it to update everywhere throughout the application then NgRx is the way to go.
2. Otherwise use services.