# how to get variable from one ts file into all other ts files in angular

Tags: angular

I have a variable called `name` in home.component.ts file, I want to use this variable globally in all the files how can I do that.

here is my code:

app.component.html

```
 <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>{{ bd_main }}</a></li>
   </ol>
</nav>
```

home.component.ts

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  bd_main= "Home";
  }
```

if we see here I am passing the `bd_main` value dynamically from home.components.ts which is one folder but I want to update that in app.component.html which is in another folder.

how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to store global data in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067218/where-to-store-global-data-in-angular)

Comment: You need to use a Service and inject it into every component you want to access the variable in.

Comment: You could use either 1. local/session storage OR 2. service

Answer (score 0):

here the subject-behaviour comes with the subject-behaviour you can get and use the value of the declared variable across the whole app. here below link is a little example of subject-behaviour hope you get some from the there. thank you.

[behaviorsubject](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-behaviorsubject)

Answer (score -1):

Create a service that will be provided in root or app module. Within this you can have the variables that you want to share between multiple components.